# How to check and add https:// to Url ? MEAN Stack application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, url, https

I'm retrieving the Url from Api data like this:

```
<div class="row copy-text">
    <a href="{{copy.Url}}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline !important;">{{copy.Title}}</a>
</div>
```

I would like to check if the Url has https:// as prefix and if it doesn't have, I want to add. Since without https:// , the Url is taking the root of localhost like this - localhost/www.test.com/

Comment: Have a look at startWith: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

You can then conditionally format the document if it starts with https or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a pipe that takes the value of `copy.Url` and prefixes it with 'https://' when needed.

The funtion would be:

```js
function addHttps(input) {
    const prefix = 'https://';
    let output = input;
    if ((input).substr(0, prefix.length) !== prefix) {
        output = prefix + input;
    }
    return output;
}
console.log('aaa');

console.log('https://aaa');
```

You would use it as:

```
<a href="{{ copy.Url | httpsPrefix }}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline !important;">{{copy.Title}}</a>
```

#### Creating the Angular pipe

Create a file named `https-prefix.pipe.ts`

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'httpsPrefix'})
export class httpsPrefixPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string): number {
        const prefix = 'https://';
        let output = value;
        if ((value).substr(0, prefix.length) !== prefix) {
            output = prefix + value;
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

Now you can use the pipe as :

```
<a href="{{ copy.Url | httpsPrefix }}" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline !important;">{{copy.Title}}</a>
```

Comment: Could you please help me in creating pipe

Comment: Updated my answer. All you need to do is import the pipe either in your component or module.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you. You need to import lodash for startsWith to work.

```js
function checkString(input) {
  if(_.startsWith(input, 'https')) {
   console.log("Yay, starts with https")
  } else {
   input = "https://" + input;
    console.log(input);
  }
}

checkString('https://abc');
checkString('localhost');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```